# Do i need to use Xcode's Image.xcassets New image set and New OSX Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm using Xcode 6.1 making a universal device app.  I have launch images and app icons for iOS 6, 7, and 8. What's the purpose of a New Image Set and a New OSX Icon in Image.xcassets. Do i have to put my images in there? I just put my images in supporting files and drag and drop into UIImageView from supporting files. Am i doing it wrong? Am i supposed to instead put all my images in New Image Set instead and not put anything in supporting files? Can i just use supporting files instead of New Image Set? Apple says New OSX Icon contains all representations of an Icon that OSX Icon provides. What Icons are they referring to? Do i have to put all my App Icons in New OSX Icon again instead of supporting files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either way, but I would choose the xcarchive.

- it is the latest approach
- it provides some help like fields for all required icons, where you can drag&drop your assets to
- items are not listed in the project file, so that remains unchanged on update (interesting if you are using version control)
- your assets are much easier to track than in a file structure

You can put almost all your images in here, only for the splash I personally prefer the file system as it offers you better control

You can still put your icons in the file system (supporting files or any other place), but you will miss the additional support and better visualization of the xcarchive. This is valid for all icons, but Apple probably refers to the app icons.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Image.xcassets, its just recommended for your App Icons and Splash Screens, and it helps you to manage same images with different sizes when you support different sizes of display (iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6+), you can read about it here:

[About Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)